# is there a way to pretty print the output of "ps" to include the "rss" memory value?

Tags: linux, terminal, ps

I have a python script which takes in processes in csv format and decides things based on what's running, it's name, and how much cpu time it's using.  I would like to add processes that also use lots of memory to said script.
The problem, however, is that the command that I have been using for csv like output does not seem to have a parameter to pretty print the RSS memory usage.  I do have access to the VSZ value however...  The command I have so far is:

```
ps -e -o "\"%p\",\"%r\",\"%U\",\"%z\",\"%C\",\"%c\",\"%a\""
"  PID"," PGID","USER    ","   VSZ","%CPU","COMMAND        ","COMMAND                    "
"22418","22418","root    ","  4956"," 0.0","my_proc","my_proc arg1 arg2"
"26175","26175","root    "," 14020"," 0.0","bash","-bash"
```

Before any one asks.. Yes I can get the vss value if I do not wish to have the value pretty printed. Example:

```
 ps -o "rss"
  RSS
  604
 2972
```

However, this doesn't get fed all nice and neatly into my script to stop stupid people from doing stupid stuff.  I've tried every letter of the alphabet I know except for the Russian ones to see if one of the values matches the pretty print values of ps.  But alas, It is not a single letter.  I can't help but feel like there is a better way to output all of the data I want in the format I want.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I can use the -o parameter in kind of a more screwy way to get the result that I wanted to achieve.  Not ideal, but it works.

```
ps  -o "\"%p\",\"%r\",\"%U\",\"" -o rss -o "\",\"%C\",\"%c\",\"%a\""
```